# Android studio does not open

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk

2021-04-11 Installed the newest version of android studio. When trying to start it splash screen apears loads up and then empty screen appears and after ten seconds it closes. Android studio icon disappears from the taskbar. I can see that android is started in task manager. P.S. Closing it and trying to run it again or running it as Administrator does not work.
[image: Empty android studio window that closes after ten seconds]

[image: Task Manager]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem upon upgrading my android studio. Something seems to be wrong with the process of importing settings and configurations from the old version.

Let's move the old configuration files to another *backup* location to see if it works. (we will not delete it, because who knows, maybe this is not the solution:) ). check these locations based on your android studio version :

**for v 4.0 and upper:**

`C:\Users\<your user name>\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio 4.x`

**for lower than 4.0 :**

`C:\Users\<yourUserName>\.AndroidStudio`

Just move the folder to another location and start the Android studio again.

If everything is as expected, a dialog should pop up asking for importing settings and configuration:
[image: configuration import dialog on android studio]

Select '**do not import**', and you are good to go.